# Research Assistant badge "Go get it" wrong redirect

Tags: feature-request, tags, badge-progress

I'd like to point out what seems a bug to me. In the next badge section of my profile, if I select the badge "Research Assistant" and then I click "Go get it" I get redirected to this page: https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current#interesting-tags
which is the one with my tags preferences in my profile. Maybe I'm wrong but shouldn't that button redirect here instead: https://stackoverflow.com/tags?

**EDIT**

In the comment sections, mostly all of us agreed that this is not a bug but a design choice. So, according to ryanyuyu's suggestion, I'm retagging this question as a feature-request instead of a bug.

I'd like the redirect on that badge's "Go get it" changed to https://stackoverflow.com/tags. I strongly believe that this would be a better design and I'm going to explain why.

First of all, let's look at **why** this badge was introduced in the first place. According to this question: [New silver badge for editing N tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119550/new-silver-badge-for-editing-n-tag-wikis), at the time the problem was that:

> Looking through the data, very few people edit many tag wikis.

So the point of the badge is to stimulate users to edit **many** tags. But how could I do that if the links to "Go get it" brings me to a page where it's very likely I'd see 10 or so **popular** tags? This kills the purpose of the badge in my opinion.

Moreover, I actually needed someone **to explain** me **how** to edit a tag from this page. I may not be the smartest guy on SO, but I think one of the point of strength of this website is that's really easy and intuitive to use. But small things like this may actually ruin this purpose.

This is my opinion. Please, feel free to correct me if you think I am mistaken.

Comment: I'm getting page not found in the first link.

Comment: Repo'd on Main, but I get taken to the tags page on Meta.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Because that's the preferences page for the OP, which you can't actually hit.

Comment: @Kendra oh.. didn't note that, thanks.

Comment: Repro on both meta and main for me.  Although, I can see the argument that this is as designed.  I mean, if there are any tags for which you'd be qualified to edit the wikis, it would probably be the tags your are following.  Or an even better suggestion, a link to your [tags tab on your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4921205/aurasphere?tab=tags).  Active tags are a good indication of the tags where your tag wiki edits would be of better quality.

Comment: After @ryanyuyu's comment, I think I understand why I couldn't repo on Meta- I have no favorite tags on Meta. So maybe this _is_ by design in that regards, but it certainly doesn't seem that intuitive to me...

Comment: @Kendra I thought that it was a design choice at first but how do you exactly edit a tag from this page? I don't think there's a way to do that... And if there is, it's not intuitive at all...

Comment: @Aurasphere you can click the link to visit the tag page itself.  Then the "improve tag info" option.  Note that your suggestions will have to be reviewed and approved until you make it to 5k rep.

Comment: @ryanyuyu ok now I understand how... But I think it shouldn't be handled this way... I don't know about you, but I only have like 10 or so favorite tags and they are quite popular like Java, for example. Who would need to edit the Java tag? I think that this badge was made to stimulate users to edit and fill **new and obscure** tags. So, according to my opinion, it should point to the tags section instead.

Comment: @Aurasphere that's a decent alternative.  If you are convinced it's not really a bug, but rather a poor design choice, you can turn your post into a [meta-tag:feature-request].  If you do, be sure to offer your alternative and why you think it's an improvement.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I took your suggestion and changed the question. Thank you.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I changed the link, it should work for anyone logged in now.

Comment: Yup, also [reported it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/249974).

Comment: This still exist.